# Restrict access to some data from db using asp.net authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Let's say I have a table `X` with columns: `Name`, `Role`. Main page is displaying list of `Name's` from table `X`. When logged in as some specific user (with ASP.NET role assigned) I want to display list of `Name's` only for rows with `Role` matching currently logged in user. Is this possible by e.g. decorating somehow EF functions? I would like to avoid harcoded `if's` in all places in application where `GetList` is called.

I'm using EF 6 with db first, ASP.NET, MVC 6.

EDIT

`GetList` method is part of GenericDataRepository:

```
    public virtual IList<T> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> dbQuery = this.Context.Set<T>();

        foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
            dbQuery = dbQuery.Include(navigationProperty);
        }

        var list = dbQuery.AsNoTracking().Where(@where).ToList();

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible but not by decorating methods. It is possible by filtering the roles in the EF layer.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya by 'filtering' you mean changing all `GetList` method?

Comment: GetList method is part of which class? Who calls that method? Can you share the code of GetList method?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I've edited post with code sample. Many other specific repositories are calling this method.

Comment: In this case the answer provided by Shoe is appropriate. If you have specific repository for role then you can have a method there which will accept role as a parameter and then create where clause for the role and call GetList method with the where clause. And then you can call method of specific repository from wherever you want with appropriate role passed as parameter.

Comment: Other way is to determine the role of current user in the repository. You need to store role of current user in some common place such as applicationContext or session or httpContext at start of each request so that repository can pick the role from there and create where clause with it and call GetList method

Comment: I have misspoken, specific repositories are not for roles, but for business entities. However I have found [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-entity-framework-row-level-security) very useful and I think this is answer for my problem. Anyway thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0):

You want a [business layer](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC351006.png). `GetList` becomes `GetListForUserRole` and takes a role parameter. Then multiple parts of your application can call this method and supply it the role.

Comment: This is something I wanted to avoid, because in real scenario I have about 10 tables with user specific data and more than 100 (estimation) places where I am calling those methods  `GetList`.